# Flurl.Http PostMultipartAsync caused some errors

Tags: flurl

I'm posting some data to a server. This piece of code works fine a few months ago. But now it threw “Flurl.Http.FlurlHttpException”.

Flurl.Http 2.3.2

```
string res = "";
try
{
   var obj = new { api_key = "key", api_secret = "secret", start = 1 };
   res = await "https://api-cn.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/faceset/getfacesets"
         .PostMultipartAsync(mp => mp
         .AddStringParts(obj)
         ).ReceiveString();

}
catch (FlurlHttpException ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

The only difference is Win10 version, from 1803 to 1809.
I changed to use "PostUrlEncodedAsync", the server returns success.
But this method can't add a file.

```
res = await apiUrl
    .PostUrlEncodedAsync(obj)
    .ReceiveString();
```

Here is the FlurlHttpException:

[image]

```
{Flurl.Http.FlurlHttpException: Call failed with status code 400 (): POST https://api-cn.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/faceset/getfacesets
   at Flurl.Http.FlurlRequest.<HandleExceptionAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Flurl.Http.FlurlRequest.<SendAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Flurl.Http.FlurlRequest.<SendAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Flurl.Http.HttpResponseMessageExtensions.<ReceiveString>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at FacePlusPlusUWP.FaceServiceClient.<SendRequestAsync>d__26.MoveNext()}
```

Comment: `FlurlHttpException` is thrown for a wide variety of reasons, including (by default) _any_ non-2xx response from the server. You'll need to provide provide the full exception details in order to narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by `FlurlHttpException.Message`, you're getting a 400 (Bad Request) response from the server. I am not familiar with the API you're using, but the first thing I would check is whether the server sent you a helpful response body. You can do that in your `catch` block like this:

```
catch (FlurlHttpException ex)
{
    var resp = await ex.GetResponseStringAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine(resp);
}
```